# Writing to an NTFS volume is disabled on 10.9.2?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ntfs

Hi I recently upgraded to 10.9.2 and I cannot write to NTFS anymore - in fact I cannot mount NTFS anymore unless I removed the the lines that allow me to write NTFS in the past in /etc/fstab...

I also tried NTFS-3G and it's the same result - the system won't mount my NTFS drive unless I reverse to the default system files or settings (which only allow me to read NTFS, without enabling the write feature).

Did Apple disable NTFS write? Why?

Also I tried Tuxera NTFS and it gives me this error message:
[image]

Comment: Did you try with paragon NTFS ?

Comment: Yes I have tried paragon NTFS.

Comment: This free solution worked for me. You need homebrew installed though. http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-write-to-a-ntfs-drive-from-os-x-mavericks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no paragon NTFS doesn't work either. The solution I had was:

In the terminal:

```
brew remove osxfuse
brew remove fuse4x
brew remove NTFS-3G
```

- Then remove everything in `/etc/fstab`
- Restart the computer
- Install Tuxera
- Plug in the hard-drive, get an error message
- Eject the hard-drive
- Restart the computer
- Plug in the hard-drive, now it works!

I think 10.9.2 installs some additional files that removed the support for NTFS-3G. For now I am happy with using Tuxera - and if anyone finds out how to use NTFS-3G, please share!

Comment: But you can't sudo brew...

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this with my memory. You don't need sudo before the brew. Instead, if you have installed fuse4x you need to remove the files - so the command is sudo rf "location."

Comment: This doesn't work for me "sudo: brew: command not found"
in fact i have tried all the solution on the net and nothing worked.
Help please!

Comment: You might have to install brew. What version is your OS X system?

Answer (score 2):

I updated my guide - turns out the issue is that osxfuse is just needed with ntfs-3g - fuse4x has to be removed.

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-write-to-a-ntfs-drive-from-os-x-mavericks/

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, using [paragon NTFS drivers](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) works perfectly.

Comment: no paragon NTFS doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found a description on how to use NTFS-3G.
According to this source updated March 2014, the package ntfs-3g is updated and you have to sym link the mount_ntfs file to a new destination, so if you have set up before and have updated your brew you may need to unlink a few dependencies and definitely link to the new destination mount_ntfs destination. Also on completion when a ntfs disk is mounted a new error is displayed but the disk still mounts and is read/writable.

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-write-to-a-ntfs-drive-from-os-x-mavericks/

I personally updated to 10.9.2 without problems with my NTFS drives. The only problem copying onto an NTFS Drive takes very long.
I have installed in my system preferences  OSXFUSE 2.6.2 and NTFS-3G 2010.10.2

Yogi